# DatabaseSchemaObjectExistsException: Table products already exists

Tags: 7, database

I try to install my module, and everything goes ok, without an error while enabling

> DatabaseSchemaObjectExistsException: Table products already exists. in
>   DatabaseSchema->createTable()...

I checked it and there wasn't the products table.

My install function is:

```
function products_schema() {
    $schema['products'] = array(
        'description' => 'The base table for products.',
        'fields' => array(
            'pid' => array(
                'description' => 'The primary identifier for a product.',
                'type' => 'serial',
                'unsigned' => TRUE,
                'not null' => TRUE,
            ),
            'name' => array(
                'description' => 'The title of this product, always treated a non-markup plain text.',
                'type' => 'varchar',
                'length' => 255,
                'not null' => TRUE,
                'default' => '',
            ),
            'created' => array(
                'description' => 'The Unix timestamp when the product was created.',
                'type' => 'int',
                'not null' => TRUE,
                'default' => 0,
            ),
            'changed' => array(
                'description' => 'The Unix timestamp when the product was most recently saved.',
                'type' => 'int',
                'not null' => TRUE,
                'default' => 0,
            ),
            'description' => array(
                'description' => 'The product description.',
                'type' => 'text',
                'not null' => FALSE,
            ),
        ),
        'indexes' => array(
            'node_changed' => array('changed'),
            'node_created' => array('created'),
        ),
        'primary key' => array('pid'),
    );

    return $schema;
}

function products_install() {
    drupal_install_schema('products');

    cache_clear_all(NULL, NULL, '*');
}

function products_uninstall() {
    drupal_uninstall_schema('products');

    $result = db_select('file_usage', 'f')
            ->fields('f')
            ->condition('type', 'product')
            ->condition('module', 'products')
            ->execute()
            ->fetchAll();

    foreach ($result as $row) {
        $file = file_load($row->fid);

        if ($file) {
            file_usage_delete($file, 'products', NULL, NULL, 0);
            file_delete($file);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your previous questions it looks like you're using Drupal 7, but the above code is partly for Drupal 6.

You don't need to add/remove the schema manually any more in Drupal 7; implementing `hook_schema()` is enough. Drupal installs the schema for you, and then when you it hits your implementation `hook_install()`, the table does already exists so it throws an error.

Just remove the calls to `drupal_install_schema()` and `drupal_uninstall_schema()`, uninstall the module and try again - it should work fine.